# Is there any way to make sure the end user gets the same voices for TTS that I use with SpeechSynthesizer?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to create a winforms application with text to speech implemented. However, the voices that are available are based on what you have installed on your OS. Is there a way to make sure the end-user also gets the correct voices that are needed, without telling them to install them manually?
This is ofcourse, if you are using SpeechSynthesizer.

If this isn't possible, I would like to know if there is an alternative to a free/open source TTS API that doesn't require your application to be on an Azure platform or being registrated somewhere (Google, TranslatingService and what not).

Comment: [Microsoft Speech Platform - Software Development Kit (SDK) (Version 11)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27226). Download also the Runtime Libraries and the voices you need. Note that there are different types of voices, e.g., : `MSSpeech_SR_en-US_TELE.msi` and `MSSpeech_TTS_en-US_Helen.msi` (Speech Recognition and TextToSpeech).

Comment: The new namespaces will be `Microsoft.Speech.Recognition` and `Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis`, from the `Microsoft.Speech` assembly.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. The problem with this is that everyone that gets my application would have to do this. I want to know if there is a way where the user doesn't have to do anything to be able to use TTS once they get my application.

Comment: Those libraries are distributed as `.msi` packages. You can include them in the Installer of your application. Adding their EULA to the installation.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those question, where the answer seems so simple and obvious, we are not even certain we understood the question right:

1. You make a installer.
2. Part of the installer is to also install those TTS packagages containing the voices.

Done. Everyone using your programm via the installer you provided has the same voices. And that (plus maybe some links in the Programm Registery) is all that Installers do.

Points of note:

- of course you need the *legal* allowance to redistiribute those packages. With some it is clear cut (like the DirectX redistirbuteable). But you need to check the licensing agreement.
- older versions of Visual Studio did have a "Installer Project". But as Installer Systems like [InstallShield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InstallShield) and [Windows Installer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) proliferated, those were cut without replacement.